# elementclickinterceptedexception in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, webautomation

i am new to robot framework and was trying to learn radio button in robot framework but got stuck up here with this below exception. Can someone please help to solve this

code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary


*** Variables ***
${browser}    firefox
${url}    https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form


*** Test Cases ***
Testing radio button and check box

    open browser    ${url}    ${browser}
    maximize browser window
    wait until element is visible    xpath://label[contains(text(),'Other')]
    
    #selecting radiobuttons
    select radio button    gender   Other
```

> Error: Testing radio button and check box
> | FAIL | ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (761,370) because another
> element  obscures it

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding additional condition before clicking that element - wait until advertisement is shown and only after that click your desired element.
So, try adding this line:

```py
wait until element is visible    xpath://div[@class='Advertisement-Section']
```

Comment: Did this help resolving your problem?

Comment: the website was not accessible later on.. really appreciate your response

Comment: In case this helped please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 type of radio button/checkbox: Default and Custom.**

1. Default element is element with input tagname, which isn't override by another element. This input element is displays in the screen
2. If this element with input tagname is pretty small (like size is 1x1) or no displays in the screen or is override by another element. Then this is a custom radio button.

How to handle 2 type of radio button:

- With default radio button, using Select Radio/ Select Checkbox with input element (like: //input xpath)
- With custom radio button/ checkbox, using Click Element to label element (like: //label[text()='Other'] xpath)

**In this site, the radio button is Custom radio button. So, we use Click Element keyword with //label element.**

In addition, you can try Default radio button/checkbox with https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/checkbox/index
or https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/radiobutton/index

(Because Select Radio Button / Select Checkbox keyword have 2 steps:

1. Check is element selected?
2. Click to element if element is not selected

So, if element with input tagname is not visible in the site (custom checkbox/radio). We cannot use click function with input tagname -> cannot use Select Radio Button/ Select Checkbox --> Only use Click Element with label)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).